# OpenArchitectureWare in the .NET world?

Tags: .net, enterprise

Is there some kind equivalent of [OpenArchitectureWare](http://www.openarchitectureware.org/) in the .NET world?

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps referring to something like [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx)?

Comment: WWF is maybe one part of that, but OAW is generator/framework for Model-Driven Architecture/Development.

Comment: I don't know enough about OAW, but it sounds like WF does that as well. Anyway, WWF is something completely different ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides a domain specific language toolkit for model driven engineering. This used to be called DSL SDK, in VS 2010 it is now called the [Visual Studio Visualization and Modeling SDK](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vsvmsdk).

I haven't used OpenArchitectureWare, so I can't comment on how similar it might be to VMSDK.